# Customise fonts with WiX Extensions

Tags: wix, wix-extension

I'm using the windows service dialog from [Windows Installer XML CommonUi Extension](http://dblock.github.io/msiext/docs/1.3/namespace_wix_1_1_extensions_1_1_common_ui.html).

I have a dark coloured banner bitmap behind the title text, so I want to change the colour of the title font.  I tried adding this to my .wxs:

```
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" Blue="255" Red="255" Green="255" />
```

This works without the extension, but now I am using the extension I get this error:

> The primary key 'WixUI_Font_Title' is duplicated in table 'TextStyle'.  Please remove one of the entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.

How can I change the font?

---

EDIT:  I resolved this in a hacky way by adding a TextStyle to the UI section like this:

```
  <TextStyle Id="My_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" Blue="255" Red="255" Green="255" />
```

and then adding custom strings to the `.wxl` file which overwrite the originals with the same text but with the font setting too.

```
  <String Id="ProgressDlgTitleInstalling">{\My_Font_Title}Installing [ProductName]</String>
  <String Id="ProgressDlgTitleChanging">{\My_Font_Title}Changing [ProductName]</String>
  <String Id="ProgressDlgTitleRepairing">{\My_Font_Title}Repairing [ProductName]</String>
  <String Id="ProgressDlgTitleRemoving">{\My_Font_Title}Removing [ProductName]</String>
```

I'm adding a bounty to the question in the hope of finding the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to override a `TextStyle` element at the moment. Either you keep your current way of doing things, or you execute an SQL query on the MSI post build to update the WixUI_Font_Title TextStyle entry.

There's a help page on executing SQL on an MSI under `Execute SQL Statements` in the MSI doc (doc\msi.chm if you have WiX installed). You could use the MSI API or DTF instead of a script, of course.

Your update statement would look something like:

```
UPDATE `TextStyle` SET `Color` = 16777215 WHERE `TextStyle` = 'WixUI_Font_Title'
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa372074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has this to say on the `Color` column:

`The value put in this column should be computed using the following formula: 65536 * blue + 256 * green + red, where red, green, and blue are each in the range of 0-255.`

Comment: Thank you that is a really detailed answer.  For the benefit of anyone reading without a WiX installation, the page in the help file is also available online here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368568(v=vs.85).aspx